# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException?

Tags: sql, derby

I'm having a little trouble with my codes since it displays this Error

'java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The number of values assigned is not the same as the number of specified or implied columns.'

I read similar  problems but still confused on how mine still displays the error. Also i tried putting "," like this in between the values but still no good. And what is prepared statement?

```
    //CONNECTION
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
    conn = 
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MetroEventsDB", 
    "root", "root");
    System.out.println("Connected");

    //Insertion
    Statement stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Users(UserID, Password, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Birthdate) VALUES('"+txtUserID.getText()+txtPassword.getText()+txtFirstName.getText()+txtLastName.getText()+gender+txtBirthdate.getText()+"')");
    }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
            }
```

Comment: Please learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement`, e.g. by reading the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Comment: Oops my bad after looking into it so long i saw the im missing the single qoutation... so it should look like this. 

VALUES('"+txtUserID.getText()+" ',  ' "+txtPassword.getText()

Comment: No it shouldn't. It should be a `PreparedStatement` with place holders. You should **not** concatenate user input into SQL queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax error in stmt.execute. The correct syntax is,

```
 stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Users(UserID, Password, FirstName, LastName, Gender, Birthdate) VALUES('"+txtUserID.getText()+"','"+txtPassword.getText()+"','"+txtFirstName.getText()+"','"+txtLastName.getText()+"','"+gender+"','"+txtBirthdate.getText()+"')");
```

Comment: yes!!....ahaha i missed that single qoutation ahha...thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

First, right-click on the Tomcat server and perform clean and clean work directories. Then, start the server again. It will solve the problem.
SQLException and others are mostly Apache tomcat issues.